# Default binding of the "this" keyword in strict mode

Tags: javascript, this

I was learning about how the **this** keyword works and I read that when a function is called plain and simple, without any context object or the new keyword, the **this** keyword simply refers to the **global / window** object. But if the function uses **strict mode**, then the **this** keyword is set to **undefined**. So I wrote this piece of code to see how it works :

```
function foo(){
    "use strict";
    alert(this.a);
}

var a = "Global A";

var obj = {
    a : "Object's A",
    foo : foo
}

setTimeout(obj.foo, 1000);
```

I thought that I would get an error saying *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined*. But to my surprise, the output was **Global A**. The function foo() is written in strict mode. But still, **this** keyword was referring to the **global** object. Why is the output **Global A** and not **TypeError** ?

Comment: Maybe cause the function declaration is not in strict mode? And note that you loose scope here: `setTimeout(obj.foo, 1000)`

Comment: @JonasW. I think that if the function body is in strict mode, it is enough to make **this** refer to undefined. But I am not 100% sure about it :+

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the browser you using and how *strictly* it been implemented.  If you are using the browser that implement strict mode perfectly, you see the error.

From the docs of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

> In strict mode, however, the value of this remains at whatever it was set to when entering the execution context, so, in the following case, this will default to undefined:

```
function f2() {
  'use strict'; // see strict mode
  return this;
}

f2() === undefined; // true
```

So, in strict mode, if this was not defined by the execution context, it remains undefined.

**Note :** *In the second example, this should be undefined, because f2 was called directly and not as a method or property of an object `(e.g. window.f2()).` **This feature wasn't implemented in some browsers when they first started to support strict mode. As a result, they incorrectly returned the window object.***

In my browser (Latest Chrome, I can see the error)

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/1mp0hq03/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! But when I executed the code (the one I mentioned in the question) in Chrome's console, the output was **Global A**. However, running the same code in JSFiddle gave **TypeError**. Weird! -_-

Answer (score 3):

```
function foo(){
    "use strict";
    alert(this.a);
}

var a = "Global A";

var obj = {
    a : "Object's A",
    foo : foo
}

setTimeout(obj.foo, 1000);
```

The output was "Global A" because,

If we try executing obj.foo() outside setTimeout function then we get "Object's A". This is because When using "use strict" in a function, the context of this keyword remains on whatever it was called upon (here it was called upon obj).

But in the above code block obj.foo is executed inside setTimeout.
As per the rule, setTimeout executes a function in global context (but not in case of arrow function).
this keyword here will be in global context, so we get "Global A".

If you are executing foo() function directly (without execution context) in chrome then you get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined.
As mentioned by @Suresh Atta
in strict mode, if this was not defined by the execution context, then it remains undefined.

If you execute foo function with execution context like window.foo() then "this" keyword will point to window object, so the result will be "Global A".

Answer (score 0):

The context of `this` depends on how the function is called.

The function `foo` is set on window object where `a` is also defined.`a` is also global variable because it is used with `var`

```js
function foo() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(window.foo) // will log the foo function
  alert(this.a);
}

var a = "Global A";

var obj = {
  a: "Object's A",
  foo: foo
}

setTimeout(obj.foo, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#the_this_problem)

> Code executed by setTimeout() is called from an execution context separate from the function from which setTimeout was called. The usual rules for setting the this keyword for the called function apply, and if you have not set this in the call or with bind, it will default to the window (or global) object. It will not be the same as the this value for the function that called setTimeout.